# How to ignore encoding certain characters in a url in java?

Tags: java, url, encoding, ascii

I have a url that looks like this: `https://123.com/screen-shot-2021-02-25-at-7.31.10%2520PM.png`

`screen-shot-2021-02-25-at-7.31.10%2520PM.png` is the file name and %25 is the encoded value for `%`

This gives me a 404. I need `%` to not be encoded. What is the proper way to ignore this when encoding a url using Google's `UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper().escape();` for Java other than using a `replace()` method?

Code for encoding:

```java
private static String FILENAME_REGEX = ".*//?(.*)$";
private static Pattern FILENAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(FILENAME_REGEX);

public String sanitizedURL(@NonNull String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    String contentUrl = url;
    Matcher matcher = FILENAME_PATTERN.matcher(url);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        String filename = matcher.group(1);
        String encodedFilename = UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper().escape(filename);
        contentUrl = url.replace(filename, encodedFilename);
        //contentUrl = contentUrl.replace("%25", "%");
    }

    // validate this is a good URI
    URI uri = new URI(contentUrl);
    return uri.toString();
}
```

Comment: I think you're assuming your 404 if due to the `%` being encoded but could be something else. It's not clear where is this code run. Is it on a webserver? an application? a command line?, a library? If it's on a server most of the time the encoding/decoding is handled by the server framework. 

Where are you getting 404? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I re-read the description. So you want to encode an url but don't want to encode the `%` character (which may result in other kind of errors, but I guess you want to use it later?) 

Yeah replace is the way to go. The fact there's not a library with "incomplete" encoding is a sign you're in a very specific scenario (which again... might bring some other kind of problems)

Answer (score 0):

Try [UrlDecoder.decode(String s, String enc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

e.g.

```
jshell> URLDecoder.decode("https://123.com/screen-shot-2021-02-25-at-7.31.10%2520PM.png", "UTF-8")
$1 ==> "https://123.com/screen-shot-2021-02-25-at-7.31.10%20PM.png"
```

Comment: I've updated the description with the code that does the encoding. If I add the decoder then it basically erases what that code does and transmit the unencoded url to the consumers. Correct me if I miss anything. Thanks!